# Connecting Broadcom device to parse cloud

Tags: c++, c, parse-platform, embedded

I am trying to connect my Broadcom device with the parse cloud, But I am not able to make it work. Does anybody know the procedure ? Please help me out with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: which broadcome device are you using ? How are you trying to connect ? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Can you please give more details, including possible code?

Comment: WE are using BCM9WCD114 Board. https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/ticc3200.i know that code is for TI device,I took it as a reference for my device.

Comment: Kindly visit http://community.broadcom.com and post your question, I've seen PARSE implementation using WICED SDK discussed there.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this example](http://kevinhoyt.com/blog/2014/11/18/spark-core-to-parse-dot-com.html) enlightening.

Essentially, instantiate a `TCPClient`, connect to the proper URL and port, then build a RESTful request verbatim, using `client.println()` to send out the headers and a combination of `sprintf()` and `client.print()` to issue the data payload.

Comment: Thank you for your response.But this is not the solution that i am looking for.I thing you didn't get my problem exactly, I know how to work on CC3000/CC3200.But i am asking for Broadcom EVB BCM9WCDPLUS114 device to connect with parse cloud.